# CDetailView Yii display Foreign Key Description

Tags: php, widget, yii

I got a trouble with Displaying FK's description on CDetailView Yii.
i have this code on Views
where the relationship between kode_kab and kode_prop is master_kab has Primary Key (composite=>kode_prop and kode_kab)

```
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
        'data'=>$model,
        'attributes'=>array(
'kode_prop'=>array(
                    'name'=>'Provinsi',
                    'value'=>master_prop::model()->FindByPk($model->kode_prop)->propinsi,
                ),
    'kode_kab'=>array(
                        'name'=>'Kabupaten/Kota',
                        'value'=>master_kab::model()->FindByPk($model->kode_kab)->kabupaten,
                    ),
```

while I run it, the error message : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()..

Could anyone help me to get solution? Thanks

Comment: if there is a problem with the foreach(), where is the code for foreach() ?

Comment: just guessing: when you have no primary keys definded in you  database, [yii bug #176](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/176) might apply to your situation. as there is nothing wrong with that code you posted this isn't a good question where one could give an answer for. You also should consider using [ActiveReord Relations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr) instead of getting each model with `findByPk()`.

Comment: sorry for getting late my response.. the problem is loading model with composite key. I had followed some instruction at Yii Forum, but it still doesn't work. I put this code into my views after the controller has been modified.. `array(‘class’=>’CButtonColumn’,'viewButtonUrl’=>’Yii::app()->controller->createUrl(“view”,$data->primaryKey)’,
‘updateButtonUrl’=>’Yii::app()->controller->createUrl(“update”,$data->primaryKey)’,
‘deleteButtonUrl’=>’Yii::app()->controller->createUrl(“delete”,$data->primaryKey)’,)`

Answer (score 0):

According to the YII documentation

> CDetailView is best used for displaying a model in a regular format (e.g. each model attribute is displayed as a row in a table.) The model can be either an instance of CModel or an associative array. 
>   CDetailView uses the attributes property to determines which model attributes should be displayed and how they should be formatted.

What you are doing is passing a model object to each attribute and foreach fails on that. 
Do the following it will work;

run your query in the controller get the results back as one model or an associative array (whatever you prefer). Call the the render view command from your controller with the model or associative array as the argument being passed. 
In your view pass the received argument as the data source to the CDetailView.

[Read more about CDetailView in the Yii documentation.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView)